# Checking circular area around enemy for player

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a HTML5 game and have what I think is a math problem. The player and enemy objects have a pos.x and pos.y value indicating where they are on the screen. I have implemented proximity check code for some enemies and am not totally happy with it. Currently the enemy is checking if the player is within a certain distance from it, 200 or -200 on the x and y axis. What this means is that the entity is scanning a 400x400 square around itself.

I would like to make this a circle with a radius of 200 instead. My code as it stands.

```
if ((player.pos.x - enemy.pos.x > 200 && player.pos.x - enemy.pos.x < 200) 
  && (player.pos.y - enemy.pos.y > 200 && player.pos.y - enemy.pos.y < 200)) {
    //Do something...
}
```

Here's my game if you want to check it out. Proximity enemies are on the second and currently last level :)

http://project.dnsalias.com/

Comment: Are you checking if the enemy is within that circle, or if the enemy's circle intrudes into that circle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very basic math.

Check that (x<sub>1</sub> - x<sub>0</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>0</sub>)<sup>2</sup> < r<sup>2</sup>

```
function inRange(p0, p1, r) {
   r = r || 200;
   var dx = p0.x - p1.x;
   var dy = p0.y - p1.y;

   return (dx * dx + dy * dy) < (r * r);
}
```

Call it like so:

```
if (inRange(player.pos, enemy.pos)) { 
    ...
}
```

You can supply a third optional argument to change the detection radius.

Comment: I really wish I had paid more attention in math class :)

Comment: Very neat solution thanks. I vaguely remember something about this in math class. I don't think I understood it at the time so never took it on board.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use the Euclidean distance function instead? It would be something like (player.pos.x - enemy.pos.x) x (player.pos.x - enemy.pos.x) + (player.pos.y - enemy.pos.y) x (player.pos.y - enemy.pos.y) = 200 x 200. Sorry I don't know the syntax for square root and square functions.